# Unable to expand MemberOf using Microsoft Graph .NET SDK using Delta Query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Expanding properties doesn't seem to work when using Delta queries. It works fine with regular user query.

Is this a limitation in Microsoft Graph API?

```
var usersInfo = graphServiceClientWithApplicationPermission.Users.Delta().Request().Expand("MemberOf").GetAsync();

// Add inital request users
foreach (var userInfo in usersInfo)
{

    // Member info doesn't seem to be expanded even if $expand=MemberOf is sent
    if (userInfo.MemberOf == null)
    {
        userInfo.MemberOf = await applicationPermissionsClient.Users[userInfo.Id].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
    }

    // MemberOf is now populated ??

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is another limitation of the Microsoft Graph and not supported.

> **Optional query parameters**
>
> If a client uses a query parameter, it must be specified in the
>   initial request. Microsoft Graph automatically encodes the specified
>   parameter into the nextLink or deltaLink provided in the response. The
>   calling application only needs to specify their desired query
>   parameters once upfront. Microsoft Graph adds the specified parameters
>   automatically for all subsequent requests. For users and groups, t
>   here are restrictions on using some query parameters:
>
> If a $select query parameter is used, the parameter indicates that the
>   client prefers to only track changes on the properties or
>   relationships specified in the $select statement. If a change occurs
>   to a property that is not selected, the resource for which that
>   property changed does not appear in the delta response after a
>   subsequent request. $expand is not supported.
>
> For users and groups beta (preview) APIs, scoping filters allow you to
>   track changes to one or more specific users or groups by objectId. For
>   example, the following request:
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq
>   '477e9fc6-5de7-4406-bb2a-7e5c83c9ae5f' or id eq
>   '004d6a07-fe70-4b92-add5-e6e37b8acd8e' returns changes for the groups
>   matching the ids specified in the query filter.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview